# How wide is the field of view on a typical DSLR/Mirrorless in-camera spot meter?

Tags: lighting

The high-end dedicated light meters can measure reflected light down to 1 degree, which could be handy if there are specific needs for them.

How does a typical in-camera meter compare, in the spot metering mode? I checked my Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mark II, but they don't give out specs for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular size of spot metering point would depend on the lens and camera. However, it can be calculated from following idea:

For example, if we look at [Nikon D70, its spot metering dot has 2.3mm diameter](http://forums.popphoto.com/showthread.php?484825-spot-metering-on-the-Nikon-D70) inside DX frame (24x16 mm). Let's say, it's 8 times smaller than vertical frame.

If you use 50 mm lens on this camera, it [will see angle of 17.7 degrees](https://www.nikonians.org/reviews/fov-tables) on that camera. That means that your spot meter will have vertical angle of view of about 2.2 degrees.

Lens' angle of view scales roughly linearly with focal length, so with 100mm lens you will have 0.9 degrees of angle for spot metering.

If you know your camera sensor and it's spot size (which might be found in manual) you can calculate angle of view for given focal length. For your OM-D E-M10 Mark II which has sensor size 17.3mm x 13.0mm and [spot meter size of ~2%](http://www.olympusamerica.com/files/oima_cckb/E-M10_Markk_II_En.PDF), I guess spot size is about 2mm. For 50mm lens, you get angular field of view of 19.5 degrees. Thus, spot metering spot is gonna be ~2 degrees for 50mm lens.

PS: I guess that is very easy to test: get a piece of white paper and draw a circle of 1 inch diameter using some black sharpie/marker. Then try to spot meter at different distances. At some point black dot will be larger than the metering spot, from there you can roughly estimate size of the dot relative to the frame size.

Comment: Why would the AoV with a 50mm lens be equivalent to a 70mm lens on a FF camera when the diagonal of an µ4/3 camera is exactly one-half the diagonal of a FF camera?

Comment: @MichaelClark i guess math is a bit off. But i tried to give OP idea how to calculate this and links

Answer (score 2):

The angular size of the spot meter will vary with the *angle of view (AoV)* given by using a particular lens. It will also vary depending on what percentage of the camera's view is covered by the spot meter. Some cameras, such as the EOS 5D Mark IV, have spot meters as small as 1.3% of the total imaging area. Others are more limited and may have a spot meter or "partial" metering area that covers 10% or more of the total imaging area.

Using a 50mm lens that yields a 46° diagonal angle of view with a FF Canon EOS 1D X Mark II (1.5% spot meter) that equates to a 4.32° AoV for the spot meter. Use a 300mm lens that gives an 8.25° diagonal AoV and the same spot meter equates to a 0.78° AoV.

Your Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mark II has a spot meter with an approximately 2% coverage area. Since the sensor has an area of about 224.9mm², 2% of that would be a circle with an area of about 4.5mm². That equates to a diameter of 2.4mm, which is 0.11X of the 21.64mm diagonal.

To calculate the angular size of the spot meter's coverage with a particular lens, you would multiply the diagonal angle of view yielded by the lens on your camera by a factor of 0.11X. With a 50mm lens a Micro Four-Thirds camera should give a diagonal AoV of about 24°, so the spot meter would cover about a 2.64° angle. The 14-42mm lens often included with the OM-D E-M10 Mark II gives a diagonal AoV of 75°-28.5°. That means the spot meter ranges from 8.25° at 14mm to 3.14° at 42mm.

To equal the 1° angle of a high end handheld light meter using the spot meter of your Olympus OM-D E-M10 Mark II, you would need a lens with an approximate focal length of 140mm.